# Occurence of a ID in every Year in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a data on a monthly base in PowerBI, which looks like this:

```
ID  Month  FY
A    1     TY
A    2     TY
A    1     LY
B    1     TY
B    2     TY
```

How can I check if the ID occurs in every FY, in a new column?

```
ID  Month  FY  Marker
A    1     TY  y
A    2     TY  y
A    1     LY  y
B    1     TY  n
B    2     TY  n
```

I try to use summarize, but I have no idea how to continue:

```
New column= summarize(data, ID, FY, "Count", distinctcount(ID))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this below **measure** -

```
Marker = 

VAR current_row_id = your_table_name[ID]

VAR fy_count_total =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[FY]),
    ALL(your_table_name)
)

VAR fy_count_for_id =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[FY]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[ID] = current_row_id
    )
)

RETURN 
IF(
    fy_count_total = fy_count_for_id , 
    "Y", 
    "N"
)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I don't think its working, I get everywhere a "yes" and I think that is not right, and I need a column, not a measure, as I have to use it as a filter later

Comment: For column, code will be little differen.  I will change it soon.

Comment: seems like I go into a memory timeout :) but its ok thx